# substitute for php rawurlencode in asp.net?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a php running code to send mms but when i converted whole code into asp.net i didnt get any substitute for rawurlencode in asp.net. i m searching this fromlast two days for nothing is working plz help me out from this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Server.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> URL-encodes a string and returns the encoded string.

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode