# AJAX + PHP self-generated fields producing blank results

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I'm back and this one might be a little tricky but we will find out! :D

Okay I am using php to self populate my `select` fields so I don't have to continuously update the `options` when new agents join. I am using ajax (javascript) for this part of the page and I have had no problems with this except with the company `select` field.

[Live site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php)

All my `select` fields work with out any problems but the Company field which will display nothing only on companies that seem to have "&" in the name. (Two companies still work with "&" in the name)

List of non-functioning Companies:
-Anthem
-Bogart
-Burnham
-Church Insurance
-Fawcett
-JRM
-Kenneth B. Brown
-Newton
-Sam F.
-Sherrill
-Wallace & Turner

PHP Company `select` code: (The if/else statement in the companies field would ideally be `if ($row['Company'] !== NULL) {
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['Company'].'">'.$row['Company'].'</option>';
                            }` but for some reason it will echo in a blank space in the `option` dropdown.)

```
<label for="company">Company</label><br />
<select id="company" name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
       <?php include 'login.php';

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `roster` ORDER BY Company ASC;");
                    echo '<option value="">' . 'Select a Company' .'</option>';
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        if ($row['Company'] == NULL) {

                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['Company'].'">'.$row['Company'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }
        ?>
</select>
```

PHP for other  `select` fields:

```
<label for="last">Last Name</label><br />
                <select id="last" name="Last_Name" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
                    <?php include 'login.php';

                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name FROM `roster` ORDER BY Last_Name ASC;");
                    echo '<option value="">' . 'Select an Agent' .'</option>';
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['Last_Name'].'">'.$row['Last_Name'].'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
</select>
```

Any Ideas on this one? If you need to see the process.php page which echos in the results then just ask! Thanks a million to anyone who helps out.

How the HTML looks when populated through php:

```
<select id="company" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
     <option value="">Select a Company</option><option value="A.R.T. Group">A.R.T. Group</option><option value="ALPHA Benefits">ALPHA Benefits</option>                    
</select>
```

I only included a few since 80ish of them is one massive line of html.

Comment: Can you post here the html code that is being generated?

Comment: Sure! Just give me one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the parameter that is being passed via ajax.  The ampersand is telling PHP that `$_GET['q']` is complete and a new `$_GET` variable is starting.

Notice the `%26` for the ampersand returns the desired result.

http://healthbenefitsohio.com/process.php?q=Anthem%20Blue%20Cross%20%26%20Blue%20Shield

Your company options should look like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.urlencode($row['Company']).'">'.$row['Company'].'</option>';
```

For good measure, I would also encode the display

```
echo '<option value="'.urlencode($row['Company']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['Company'],ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';
```

Comment: I will give this a try in just a few minutes and I'm hopping it works! This has been one heck of a learning experience for my first time ever trying php.

Comment: Hmm This is interesting: process.php?q=Anthem%20Blue%20Cross%20%26%20Blue%20Shield, When I was using the console in Google Chrome It showed these results but it included the "&" symbol. If it displayed it like this I could have clearly seen what was wrong.

Comment: Google chrome showed the ampesand.. That's how i identified the bug.

Comment: Well I greatly appreciate the help with this and your answer did solve my question. Is there a better console to use so I don't run into this problem again or should I just get familiar with how the browser renders text? I write a lot of html but I was under the impression that & = "&amp;".

Comment: read up on urlencoding(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode) and html encoding(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882307/when-to-use-htmlspecialchars-function) -- for dev and debug i use firebug and chrome

Comment: Also, your #nav and .navl would look better if you remove the left margins and set widths to 100%

Comment: Oh trust me that design would look a lot better with a million things done to it but I am only allowed to do the development on this and that is how they wanted the nav to be lol. You should have seen the html from who ever designed/developed this before me.http://healthbenefitsohio.com/Old%20HBO/index.html  ---
What I had to work with