# Set the value of an html tag attribute within a php clause

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Long story short...

This is the html tag which I want to set the attribute:

`echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='".$phpvar."'>";`

$phpvar can contain any text and symbols (including quotes and double quotes) in it

How can I properly escape/convert the string to make it display correctly?

Thank you everyone!

**EDIT**
Thank you everyone for helping me out!
Ok, if anybody else gets stuck with this, this solved my problem:

1. Use double quotes (") surrounding the value of the attribute, because HTML only has an entity code for doubles (") and they won't bug like singles (') do.
2. Convert/encode the string with either htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars().

Comment: You could try `.urlencode($phpvar)` and here is a good question on `urlencode` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode.

Comment: Or `htmlspecialchars ($phpvar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is made for this kind of thing.

```
$phpvar= '"&#test"';
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.htmlentities($phpvar).'">';
```

will output

```
<input type='text' name='name' value='&quot;&amp;#test&quot;'>
```

The text field will display `"&#test"`.

Comment: I think thats what I was looking for, thanks! But by the way, what is the difference between htmlentities(), strip_tags(), urlencode() and htmlspecialchars() in simple words?

Comment: `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are identical. I just prefer the shorter. `strip_tags()` is for removing html tags like `<p>`. `urlencode()` is for encoding URLs like a link that need special characters in it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, just another thing, I noted that neither htmlentities() nor htmlspecialchars() convert the single quotes, and as I mentioned above, $phpvar can contain anything including both types of quotes in the same string

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect quotes being reversed. This way single quotes won't cause an issue. The problem is HTML does not have an entity code for a single quote. So by making sure `value=""` uses double quotes all entities will be converted in away that will be displayed in the text field including single quotes. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To send the value through to your php file you need to encode characters like `&`, `"`, `'`, and many more symbols that are not recognized by the browser.

To do this you can use `urlencode()` to turn those symbols into the html symbol entities that it can render.

Here is how it should look,

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='".urlencode($phpvar)."'>";
```

Here is some helpful questions on stackoverflow that will help you out.

[Why should I use urlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode)

[AJAX + PHP self-generated fields producing blank results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062594/ajax-php-self-generated-fields-producing-blank-results)

Best of luck mate!

Comment: Thanks but the text inside $phpvar will be used in html not as an url

Comment: They encode the symbols in the same way as html but `htmlentities($phpvar)` is a better option. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strip_tags()` or `urlencode()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

or change your echo statement, if the value of $phpvar will only contain single quote so using double quote is a better practice

`echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="$phpvar">';`

Comment: Well thats a workaround, but $phpvar can contain either single quotes, double quotes or both at any moment...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what special characters you want to remove from the variable. As you mentioned about the quotes, the following code will remove single and double quotes from string.

```
<?php    
$quotes = array('"', "'");

echo str_replace($quotes, "", "Hello Wor'l'd of PHP");
```

Comment: That's useful, thanks, but that doesn't work with other symbols like # & etc... I think I'll stick with urlencode, htmlentities or htmlspecialchars