# No responses from google places text search api

Tags: php, mysql, curl, xampp

I am getting no responses from google places text search API

**Here is my php code :**

```
$string=$row["PropertyTitle"].'+'.$row["LocalityName"].'+'.$row["CityName"];
$details_url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=".$city."&key=someapikey";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$geoloc = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
print_r($geoloc);
```

it does not even give the below result

```
{ 
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

What is the mistake i am doing and How can i fix this ?

Comment: oh great, you posted your API key. By the way, did you properly encode your `$city`?

Comment: You are passing '$city' in the query parameter but it seems like you haven't defined.

Comment: You might also consider running your strings through `urlencode()` just to be on the safe side. It may result in a broken URL otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing `$ch = curl_init();`

And I guess your `$string` should be named `$city`. Also, use `urlencode` on `$city`. See [Why should I use urlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode).

```
<?php
$city = urlencode( $row["PropertyTitle"].'+'.$row["LocalityName"].'+'.$row["CityName"] );
$details_url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=".$city."&key=API_KEY";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$geoloc = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
print_r($geoloc);
```