# Why we use UrlEncode

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I generally use the code `_uri = Server.UrlEncode(_uri);` before any page redirection with parameter values but I don't know the significance of using UrlEncode for this.I want to know the benefit of using UrlEncode.

Comment: it will encode any special characters like &,= in the values of the parameters

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this encoding? @Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: If you don't use it, you could have characters in your URL that are interpreted in the wrong way. It is somewhat like putting quotes around a string to tell the compiler/server not to worry about what's inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> URLEncode returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters other than – (hyphen) _ (underscore), and . (period) have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits that correspond to the charactor code and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. Spaces can alternatively be encoded as %20.  20 is (16*2)+(1*0)=32 in decimal, which is the ASCII code for space.

### Example

If You write

```
Response.Write(Server.URLEncode("http://www.technologycrowds.com"));
```

then Result will come like this

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Etechnologycrowdst%2Ecom
```

Comment: Erm, no? This is not an explanation at all. How could it be helpful?

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode

Answer (score 3):

Consider a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/index.aspx?redirectUrl=http://example.com/index.aspx?someValue=123
```

How would you parse that URL?  Which `://` separates the protocol from the address?  Which `?` separates the address form the values?  It would get confusing fast, because the characters being used in the query string value have significant meanings in URLs.

Instead, consider this version:

```
http://example.com/index.aspx?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.aspx%3FsomeValue%3D123
```

Now none of the characters being used in the query string value have other significant URL meanings.  It's just a single string, so the entire URL can be parsed easily.

URL-encoding values allows us to treat those values as *values*, and not as parts of the URL itself.

Comment: this should be the real answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings.Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers.

See Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx