# Link which points on a backend endpoint is displayed incorrectly in the email text

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, graphql, email-verification

I try to include a verificaton link as plain text into an email which points on a GraphQL endpoint but browser/email client doesn't display it correctly.

It can't parse symbols like !,",{,} which I need for the link query and ultimately it becomes broken. 
Also, I've tried to include the link into href attribute of the a tag but the problem is, that it fails to parse double quotes also.

Link example:

`https://blahblah.now.sh/graphql?query=query($email:String!,$token:String!){verifyEmailToken(email:$email,token:$token)}&variables={"email":"22yiba@clearmail.online","token": "221c4dfd976f3ac22f"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain characters have special meaning in the context of a URL. You should use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to escape these characters. The resulting URL would be:

https://blahblah.now.sh/graphql?query=query%28%24email%3AString%21%2C%24token%3AString%21%29%7BverifyEmailToken%28email%3A%24email%2Ctoken%3A%24token%29%7D%26variables%3D%7B%22email%22%3A%2222yiba%40clearmail.online%22%2C%22token%22%3A%20%22221c4dfd976f3ac22f%22%7D

For additional details, see [Why should I use urlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode) and [Should I use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent for encoding URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540753/should-i-use-encodeuri-or-encodeuricomponent-for-encoding-urls)