# GET not displaying one of the inputs

Tags: php

I have some PHP and a HTML Form, two of the inputs are echoing fine the first input is not, and its something to do with the URL as when I remove the "+" from the fullname, the input then displays. Why is the url doing "+" and how can I fix it so the fullname input works

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
<input id="fullname" name="fullname "type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Legal Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
</div>


session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["staff"])){
header("Location: default.php");
exit(); }

$name = $_GET['fullname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$ContactNumber = $_GET['ContactNumber'];


echo $name. "</br>" . $email. "</br>" . $ContactNumber.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I use urlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode)

Comment: @maio290 I am new to PHP sorry

Comment: The + at the end of the fullname didnt not appear until I added the isset session at the top, prior to that the fullname did display

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

The variable is there, but the `+` is a reserved sign in url encoding.

If you `var_dump` your `$_GET` superglobal, you'll get something like that:

```
array(1) { ["param_"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

If you want to use a plus in your variables, you have to use `%2B` because the `+` means whitespace in a URL. So if you want to pass `hello world` you'd be writing `hello+world` - just can't find a source for it because the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) is a bit harsh to read.

So, the reason why your code fails is just a typo: `"fullname "` remove the whitespace...

For further information, just check out the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding