# python beautifulsoup if-in-statement doesn´t work correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with the web scraping code below. The code works, but if the entered product is not just a single word and contains for example also a number like "Playstation 4" it fails. The problem seems to be in this line `if product in str(product_name):`

I tried many different variations like `product_name.text` or `product_name.string`, but it won´t correctly check if the string `product` is in the converted object `product_name` if it is not just one word.

If I use `print(product_name.text)` I get exactly the result that I would expect, but why can´t I use the if-in-statement correctly with `product_name.text` or `str(product_name)`?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product = input("Please enter product: ")

URL = "http://www.somewebsite.com/search?sSearch=" + product

website = requests.get(URL)

html = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'html.parser')

product_info = html.find_all('div', class_="product--main")


product_array = []
for product_details in product_info:
    product_name = product_details.find('a', class_="product--title product--title-desktop")
    if product in str(product_name):
        product_array.append(product_name.text.replace('\n', '')+'; ')
        discounted_price = product_details.find('span', class_="price--default is--discount")
        if discounted_price:
            product_array.append(discounted_price.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\xa0€*','').replace('from','') + ';\n')
        else:
            regular_price = product_details.find('span', class_="price--default")
            product_array.append(regular_price.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\xa0€*','').replace('from','') + ';\n' if regular_price else 'N/A;\n')

with open("data.csv", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("product; price;\n")
    for object in product_array:
        text_file.write(object)
```

Comment: please add the values of `product` and `product_name` for the failing test

Comment: Check type(product_name) then you will see. You can use iin or not

Comment: Try removing code to narrow it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Also, if there are spaces perhaps switch to if re.match(.....): instead as definitely will allow for spaces between words in pattern matching

Comment: thx for all the answers... the value of `product` for example is `"Playstation 4"` and the value of `product_name` are scraped product names like `<div>Playstation 4</div>` and `<div>Playstation 5</div>` and I want to sort out the Playstation 5 result.

Using `type(product_name)` returns `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. What do you mean with iin or not?

I had stripped all the code after `if product in str(product_name):` and replaced it with a simple print to find my mistake, but I don´t get why it´s not working after the string conversation.

Thx for the tip, I will try it with `re.match`.

Comment: What is the actual url please?

Comment: Maybe check for Unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why should I use urlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667942/why-should-i-use-urlencode)

> I tried many different variations like product_name.text or product_name.string,
> but it won´t correctly check if the string product is in the converted object  product_name if it is...
>
> **not just one word**.

> `URL = "http://www.somewebsite.com/search?sSearch=" + product`

Please look what happens with query string when you use concatenation:
[image]

---

So please consider updating your code like below:
[image]

Comment: I wrote the code new from scratch and made the changes. Now it seems to work. thx :)