# How do I keep a URL from breaking at the spaces? No method is working

Tags: php, url, break

I am having a lot of trouble with this, $report is breaking at the space in the URL, and I Have been trying to fix this problem for a couple of days now, and nothing is working.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" method="post" action=
    <?
         echo "\"reports1.php?report=";
         echo rawurlencode($report);
         echo "\"";
    ?>              
>
```

...

```
if(isset($_GET['report'])){
        $report = $_GET['report'];
        echo "<script>alert('All reports will be appended to \"".$report."\" until GET and POST data are cleared.')</script>";
    }
    elseif($country != NULL){
        $report = $date." ".$country." ".$topic;
    }

    elseif($country == NULL){
        $report = $date." ".$region." ".$topic;
    }
```

...

Here is an example; the $report is getting $_GET'ted as

"2011-05-08  ",
even though it should be 
but it is $_POSTING as "2011-05-08 Brazil Botulism"
"reports1.php?report=2011-05-08  "

Comment: What do you mean by breaking? Where, in the browser? Can you show an example?

Comment: Here is an example; the $report is getting $_POSTED as

"2011-05-08 ", even though it should be "2011-05-08 Brazil Botulism"
"reports1.php?report=2011-05-08 "

Comment: Can you show us the output from the code that you give in the first example please.

Comment: When I am using urlencode I get "reports1.php?report=2011-05-08++"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode ref

Answer (score 4):

`urlencode()` will work.

Make sure you wrap the address in quotes, and it is on one line:

```
<form ... action="reports1.php?report=2011-05-08%20Brazil%20Botulism">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `trim()` function to remove unwanted whitespace in the beginning and the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

well you dont need to raw it,

echo "hi";

will work fine with ya, in case of ur code above there is only one problem that u use $_POST method for ur form not $_GET

> form onsubmit="return validate(this)"
>   method="post" action=
>   should be

a very nice and easy debugin code that can help u is retriving all $_GETs and assign them to vars,

with

```
foreach($_GET as $var=>$val)$$var=$val;
```

this code wil get all posted gets and assign them to variables with there own name, ($report instead of $_GET['report'];) u can use this function on all $_post and $_get to know where is exactly the problem :)..

hope it helps

Comment: Please use correct grammar and spelling while contributing to the site, thanks!