# Process percent-encoded string with special characters in PHP

Tags: php, string

I got an string like:

> M%C3%B2nica

So I need to get something like "Mònica".

Which is the best way in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo rawurldecode ('M%C3%B2nica'); // prints Mónica
```

You can either use urldecode() or rawurldecode(), but in your case it probably doesn't make a difference. (read more on this here: [urlencode vs rawurlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode))

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer : `urldecode();`