# Curl returns 400 bad request (url with spaces)

Tags: php, curl

When i use curl library and try to get image from url i get 400 bad request error.
I founded that problem is with encoding url.
But in my case it's not work, because my url - it's path to image on server side - like

```
http://example.com/images/products/product 1.jpg
```

I understand that user spaces in name files it's bad practice, but it's not my server and not i created those files.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($url));
echo $ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

When i use urlencode function - curl return http_code = 0

**Updated**

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
```

**doesn't work, server return 404 error.**

Comment: is such a URL possible ( with space ). Space turns into `%20` when we type space in URL

Comment: @diEcho what? of course it is possible. It doesn't turn into %20 by itself - some clients can do that, but certainly not all of them, and always it isn't even possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Does this maybe work?

```
$url = 'http://host/a b.img';
$url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo $ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) function:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, rawurlencode($url));
echo $ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

[rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) must be always preferred. [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) is only kept for legacy use. For more details look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996161/2648942).

Answer (score 0):

You can't urlencode the entire string because that will encode the slashes and others that you need to remain unencoded.  If spaces are your only problem, this will do:

```
str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
```

Comment: @yAnTar what is the resulting URL after `str_replace`?

Comment: I would to post really url, but parser on stackoverflow cut the symbols. I posted only filename 
real filename - Michal Dziekan 016-thumb-600x791-188072.jpg

After replacing - Michal+Dziekan+016-thumb-600x791-188072.jpg

Comment: @techie_28 either one should work, but `%20` is more technically correct now.  Go ahead and give that a try.

Comment: for me, '+' works fine, probably depends on the server

Answer (score -1):

Using curl has more challenges than other ways. Simply use shell_exec

```
$cmd = "curl -k -v -X POST 'https://serveraddress:8243/?foo=bar' -H 'Authorization: Basic cEZ.....h'";

$result = shell_exec($cmd);         
$output =  json_decode($result,true);
print_r($output);
```