# 400 bad request curl php

Tags: php, curl

When i request method "`POST`" from domain `abc.com` to `x.abc.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8A0617CA8A47BEE532FFBEA95FCE6BE3; Path=/ccp/; Secure
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2020 07:20:10 GMT
Connection: close
Server:
```

=============================================================

This is my curl request

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add the code in the question so that one can copy paste as soon as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl returns 400 bad request (url with spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342149/curl-returns-400-bad-request-url-with-spaces)

Comment: why are you putting all those "access-control" headers into your request?? 1) Those are **response** headers which are intended to be used by the responding server, not the requesting client. They are meaningless in the context of a request. 2) They are all related to CORS requests anyway, and your request is not being launched from a browser, so it cannot be subjected to CORS restrictions. If you're going to add some headers to your request, make sure you actually understand why you are adding them...

Comment: ...[cont'd]: Don't just just blindly copy something you saw elsewhere without knowing its purpose! In this particular case it's harmless, luckily, but you could easily cause problems in your code by using code you don't properly understand (e.g. accidentally introducing security holes, or data corruption, etc etc.)

Comment: I put access-control because i have project font-end, i call api from client to server (php) so i put access-control.

Comment: http://codepad.org/tEROJWMX
Link my code. When i deploy in heroku or run in local, it work perfect. But i run in server (of company), it not working.

Comment: https://i3international.com/phpinfo.php
This is  php info