# PHP Escape GET data

Tags: php, web-services, get

If I am using a GET parameter in a web service call, what type of escaping should I do? I was thinking of just using htmlentities.

Example:
http://example.com/search.php?search=1234

Search.php

Uses $_GET['search'] to make a web service call to another service.

Comment: htmlentities is not an escape function...

Comment: Just to clarify, do you know precisely which web service you will be passing the user input too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the URL, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) data.

HTML entities are only relevant in an HTML context.
Perhaps [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) can clear up that confusion.

Comment: the linked content (and answer) is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @deceze answer, it might be a better times to use `rawurlencode`.

[urlencode vs rawurlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/996139/1624960)