# What is the difference between urlencode and rawurlencode?

Tags: php, security

I read the reference question [urlencode vs rawurlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode) in the way, that I should use `rawurlencode`

e.g.

> If interoperability with other systems is important then it seems rawurlencode is the way to go.

But why was `urlencode` invented then? Does it mean this function is useless?

Comment: I usually use urlencode in all my applications and they all work nicely. It's all about RFC 3986

Comment: Not useless, but it uses special characters and it is often easy to get confused rawurlencode is better

Comment: Why not ask that as a comment on the original answer? I think your question is on the verge of duplicate, if you think it isn't, edit it so it's obvious.

Comment: It was invented for the HTML standards, see RFC1866 (HTML 2.0), in specific here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866#section-8.2 - it basically saves network bandwidth for commonly entered text. The space symbol is used quite often within text. Not much of an issue nowadays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on what you are after. A main difference between them is the standard that they encode to of course, but also spaces.

`urlencode` encodes the same way that form data is encoded

`urlencode` encodes spaces as `+` symbols while `rawurlencode` encodes them as `%20`.

Therefore when dealing with form data, urlencode would be preferable (as forms encode spaces as + signs too). Otherwise rawurlencode is a wiser choice in my opinion.

For example, you may want to mimic form data being submitted via a URL, you would use urlencode.

Comment: ' therefore when dealing with form data, urlencode would be preferable (as forms encode spaces as + signs too). ' - can you explain it with an example ? What is the problem if we use `rawurlencode` here ?