# How to have apostrophes in PHP string?

Tags: php, string, url, escaping

Part of my `PHP` code includes the construction of a `URL` string as follows:

```
$msg = $_REQUEST["msg"];
$content =  'action=sendmsg'. 
                '&user='.rawurlencode($username). 
                '&password='.rawurlencode($password). 
                '&to='.rawurlencode($destination). 
                '&text='.rawurlencode($msg);
```

When `$msg` happens to contain an apostrophe, it get sent as `"\'"`.

What do I need to do to make sure the backslash is not inserted by `PHP`?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to check out stripslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want to send the `$content` variable instead of just stripping the backslashes, Consider to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) instead of `rawurlencode()`. Also, you can use the function once for your `$content` variable.

```
$content = urlencode($content);
```

**UPDATE:** both `urlencode` and `rawurlencode` may not fit your case. Why don't you just send out the `$content` without URL encode? How do you send our the query string? If you are using cURL, you do not need to encode the parameters.

Comment: What is the difference between `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()`?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode

Comment: update the answer. just curious how you use the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. Stipslashes
2. or put the string in "" and add ' where you want.