# How can I use &#39; without slash?

Tags: php, html, single-quotes

I want to post an input box that have single quote inside it to a php file.I've used ' but it sends some backslashes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="legal_natural" value="$store_info[&#39;legal_natural&#39;]">
```

result:

```
$store_info[\'legal_natural\']
```

Please tell me how can I avoid backslashes when I post ' to a PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

See this : [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331037/how-to-have-apostrophes-in-php-string)

Here's an answer from that question:

Assume you want to send the `$content` variable instead of just stripping the backslashes, Consider to use urlencode() instead of `rawurlencode()`. Also, you can use the function once for your `$content` variable.

```
$content = urlencode($content);
```

UPDATE: both urlencode and rawurlencode may not fit your case. Why don't you just send out the $content without URL encode? How do you send our the query string? If you are using cURL, you do not need to encode the parameters.