# PHP error using & in url

Tags: php, url

There is a string `XX&YY` and I'm passing it to another page. ie, `localhost/sample/XX&YY/1` for some processing. Now when I try getting the name value on the other side I'm able to get only `XX` and not full `XX&YY`. How to rectify it? Any ideas?

Note : here is my url `localhost/sample.php?name=somevalue&pageno=somevalue has been url re-written to localhost/sample/name/pageno`.

Comment: are you using URL rewritting? anyway you should encode the & as it's used to determine whenever you have a new parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the URL . You can use `rawurlencode()` or `urlencode()` to encode your URL.

**sidenote:** [Difference of the 2 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this is the URL to your script:

```
http://localhost/sample/name/pageno
```

Which is then rewritten by your web server to this:

```
http://localhost/sample.php?name=somevalue&pageno=somevalue
```

Then, this is how you should format the URL:

```
$url = sprintf('http://localhost/sample/%s/%s', 
    urlencode('XX&YY'), 
    urlencode('1')
);
```