# PHP urlencode - encode only the filename and dont touch the slashes

Tags: php, url, encoding, urlencode, encode

```
http://www.example.com/some_folder/some file [that] needs "to" be (encoded).zip
urlencode($myurl);
```

The problem is that `urlencode` will also encode the slashes which makes the URL unusable. How can i encode just the last filename ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/some_folder/some file [that] needs "to" be (encoded).zip';
$pos = strrpos($str, '/') + 1;
$result = substr($str, 0, $pos) . urlencode(substr($str, $pos));
```

You're looking for the last occurrence of the slash sign. The part before it is ok so just copy that. And `urlencode` the rest.

Comment: Working perfectly with the missing ")" at the end :)

Comment: I would also use rawurlencode instead of urlencode for filenames

Comment: Are we positive that a forward slash could not exist in a URL somewhere after a ?, even if it shouldn't be there? Technically it should be escaped, but what if it's not. ie. "https://example.com/thing?redirect=www.example.com/other-thing". Maybe it doesn't matter because the URL is not valid, but would there be a solution to properly encode this entire string?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996161/4233593) you should be using [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) instead of `urlencode`.

To answer your question, instead of searching for a needle in a haystack and risking not encoding other possible special characters in your URL, just encode the whole thing and then fix the slashes (and colon).

```
<?php
$myurl = 'http://www.example.com/some_folder/some file [that] needs "to" be (encoded).zip';
$myurl = rawurlencode($myurl);
$myurl = str_replace('%3A',':',str_replace('%2F','/',$myurl));
```

Results in this:

> http://www.example.com/some_folder/some%20file%20%5Bthat%5D%20needs%20%22to%22%20be%20%28encoded%29.zip

Answer (score 0):

Pull the filename off and escape it.

```
$temp = explode('/', $myurl);
$filename = array_pop($temp);

$newFileName = urlencode($filename);

$myNewUrl = implode('/', array_push($newFileName));
```

Comment: this is a slow solution. No need to dump the string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Jeff Puckett's answer but as a function with arrays as replacements:

```
function urlencode_url($url) {
    return str_replace(['%3A','%2F'], [':', '/'], rawurlencode($url));
}
```