# urlencode converts spaces to + but link isn't working

Tags: php, url, urlencode

After running urlencode() on an URL, the function will convert spaces inside the URL to "+". However when i try to access the encoded URL, it's not working. Looks like my server only supports %20

How do i need to do to make my server supports + as encoded spaces ? Or how can i urlencode the spaces to %20 instead ?

```
urlencode("http://www.example.com/just some test.zip");
```

Result: http://www.example.com/just+some+test.zip

Comment: http://php.net/rawurlencode

Comment: but i would prefer to make my server supports + instead of %20 ... how do i do that ?

Comment: Can't you use urldecode() on the encoded string?

Comment: Yes, but i want to use plus signs instead. How do i enable it on my server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode()`,

[difference between rawurlencode and urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode)