# urlencode/rawurlencode and automatic decoding

Tags: php

Among other differences, `urlencode` and `rawurlencode` encode spaces differently. `+` and `%20` resepctively. According to the PHP docs, variables are decoded automatically. How does PHP “know” which way to decode it?

I used to use `urlencode` until I read here on SO that the raw counterpart is generally better. I must say, I've never run into any decoding problems but am curious as to how it works and if you think there are any scenarios when `rawurlencode` would cause issues due to the automatic decoding.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/996161/1207346

Comment: Personally urlencode and urldecode never gave me any problems, I've never had to use rawurlencode.

Comment: Values in `$_GET` seem to be automatically decoded according to *both* standards, i.e. both `%20` and `+` are spaces. Which is pretty weird, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` character is encoded by both function as %2B, so no confusion is possible.

To safely decode any version, PHP only has to transform each `%XX` into its corresponding character and transform each `+` to a space. This is what `urldecode` does.

`rawurlencode` shouldn't cause issues as all it does is encode a wider range of chars into their %XX counterparts. Those will be decoded safely by any version of the function.