# Curl Issue: Umlauts in URL

Tags: php, curl

I have a Problem fetching URLs with Umlauts (e.g. 'ü') in it.

For example "[http://www.ebay.de/bhp/kühlschrank](http://www.ebay.de/bhp/k%C3%BChlschrank)":

My Script:

```
function getUrlContent($url)
{
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 10 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"UTF-8");


    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    $i = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i);
    return $response;

}

$url="http://www.ebay.de/bhp/kühlschrank";
$response = getUrlContent($url);
```

It always results in a 404.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to encode the url before pass to getUrlContent()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/php-urlencode-vs-rawurlencode

Answer (score 2):

You need to `utf8_decode()` the $url parameter and add a **`cURL`** parameter. `FOLLOWLOCATION`

```
<?php
function getUrlContent($url)
{
    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 10 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); //<------- I added it here !
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"UTF-8");


    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    $i = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i);
    return $response;

}

$url="http://www.ebay.de/bhp/kühlschrank";
$response = getUrlContent(utf8_decode($url)); //<---- utf8 decode !!
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://pages.ebay.com/messages/DE_page_not_responding.html?RlogId=t6awipp%60c%7Fs%3F%3Ctof2e34e*%3B4c3-144258a5d5d-0x1f0
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 1233
    [request_size] => 264
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 1
    [total_time] => 1.235
    [namelookup_time] => 0.266
    [connect_time] => 0.485
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.485
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 4611
    [speed_download] => 3733
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 4611
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.735
    [redirect_time] => 0.469
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 66.135.205.14
    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.9
    [local_port] => 61581
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: Certainly, I've just tested and the page expects ISO-8859-1 in the URL. For some reason, I had assumed that all modern browsers defaulted to UTF-8...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I think Google Chrome `Version 32.0.1700.107 m` is not.

Comment: With this Version the response-HTML-Code is different from the one in a Browser. (http://pages.ebay.com/messages/DE_page_not_responding.html?RlogId=t6awipp%60c%7Fs%3F%3Ctof2e34e*%3B4c3-144258a5d5d-0x1f0)

Answer (score 1):

A poor-man's alternative solution is to feed Curl with a plain US-ASCII verion of the URL:

```
http://www.ebay.de/bhp/k%C3%BChlschrank
```

I got mine by fetching the page with Firefox and copying the URL from the location bar but you can also do it from PHP:

```
// Assuming UTF-8
$url="http://www.ebay.de/bhp/" . rawurlencode("kühlschrank");
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl doesn't encode the URL for you, you have to do it. That is, it has to be URL encoded. Strictly you should not just decode the UTF8, as its not the same thing. You should use [rawurlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php):

```
    <?php
function getUrlContent($url)
{
      //echo $url;
      $ch = curl_init();


      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 10 seconds
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"UTF-8");


      $response=curl_exec($ch);
      $i = curl_getinfo($ch);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($i);
      return $response;

}

$url="http://www.ebay.de/bhp/" . rawurlencode( "kühlschrank" );
$response = getUrlContent($url);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Array
(
    [url] => http://www.ebay.de/bhp/k%C3%BChlschrank
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 1007
    [request_size] => 94
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.669702
    [namelookup_time] => 0.606492
    [connect_time] => 0.744441
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.744556
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 44032
    [speed_download] => 26371
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.386599
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 23.2.16.17
    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 10.1.1.2
    [local_port] => 56592
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```