# opendir not reading full file name

Tags: php, opendir

I want to open a directory in php and then display the link for downloading that file.

this is what I am trying.

```
if(is_dir($dir))
{
  $op=opendir($dir);
  echo"Files in the directiry are<br>";

   while(($file=readdir($op))!==false)
   {
    if(strpos($file,$ext,1))
   {
      echo "<a href=apps/".$file .">".$file."</a><br>";
    }  
  }
}
```

this shows downloading links but only upto space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP function [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) apparently gives you better system coverage. [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) actually doesn't work on my localhost.

```
<?php

$dir = 'apps';
$ext = 'pdf';

if(is_dir($dir))
{
  $op=opendir($dir);
  echo"Files in the directory are<br>";

   while(($file=readdir($op))!==false)
   {
    if(strpos($file,$ext,1))
   {
      echo '<a href="apps/' . rawurlencode($file) . '">' . $file . '</a><br>';
    }  
  }
}

?>
```

More on the subject here: [urlencode vs rawurlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/urlencode-vs-rawurlencode)