# Should PHP header locations be encoded?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

Should PHP header locations be encoded?

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
header("Location: ".rawurlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
```

If so, why, when, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to encode it, if you have some special chars (defined in [RFC1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt)) in your URL. Especially you should encode all URLs with the following characters: {}|\^~[]` (as of RFC1738)

Comment: True, but the relevant specs are RFC 7231 and RFC 3986.

Comment: What will happen if I do not?  Will PHP's `REQUEST_URI` ever need encoding or will it already be so when it is passed to the server?  Should I use `rawurlencode()` to encode?

Comment: @user1032531 I never tried that, but maybe a broken link or so, maybe also nothing. PHP seems to be really strange on encoding input. I trieded the whole string only the ` got encode. So yes you should also encode `REQUEST_URI`. It depends on your requirements, whenever you need rawurlencode or urlencode. A detail answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/urlencode-vs-rawurlencode
@JulianReschke prior to 5.3 PHP uses the RFC1738, but you are right.