# Secure string variable in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Finally i am migrating from sql to PDO but i am little bit confused about string'

Here is my code which work perfect and secured from sql injection

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost;dbname=sqlitest" , "root" , "");
$catId = $_GET["Id"];  //Id = int eg:1
$query = "select * from viewimage where ImageCategory =? ";
$result = $connect->prepare($query);
$result->execute(array($catId));
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($fetch = $result->fetch()):
    $img = $fetch["Image"];
    echo "<img src='img/event/$img' height='300px' width='300px'>";
endwhile;
```

but when `$catId = $_GET["Id"];`  where Id is a string string  eg: ColorDay and i try

```
localhost/test/view.php?id=ColorDay'
```

no image display in above case if I put

```
localhost/test/view.php?id=1'
```

result same and redirect on same page containing image,which command should i use to secured from 'No Image Result' in string

Comment: Is the `'` part of your URL?  Are you saying that `1'` returns an image, but `ColorDay'` does not?  I don't know if I understand the question here.

Comment: well, if `ImageCategory` contains only integers, what do you expect to show up when you look for the string `ColorDay`? That's like wondering why there aren't any green socks in package marked "red socks".

Comment: ' is not a part of my url,both return image 1 and ColorDay, but when i checked for sql injection with ' , 1' return image,ColorDay' return no image

Comment: *Ah,* I see what you're trying to do. You're testing to see that if someone adds `'` at the end of the URL, to see if it will trigger an injection, *correct?*. If so, just use a conditional statement, then echo a different message if no result.

Comment: yes currently i am testing for sql injection error @Fred-ii-

Comment: Seems like I'm the only one so far who understood your question.

Comment: The point of using parameterized queries is that SQL injection is now a thing of the past!  You never have to worry about what will happen if someone adds a `'`.  All you need to do is check how many results your query returns and do something if it's 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

`$result->execute(array($catId));`

Makes your code secure. If the image is not returned, it's another problem but to me it looks like it's an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. Encode any string that goes into your url and decode data before you use in application ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996161/747609))
2. Watch out for [XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996141/747609), don't just output string from your database to browser.
3. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/747609) on how to completely prevent SQL Injection.