# Does zf2 have an alias for urlencode?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, alias, urlencode

Does zf2 have an alias for `urlencode`?

In zf2, if I want to do a `rawurlencode`, I use:

```
$escaper = new Zend\Escaper\Escaper();
echo $escaper->escapeUrl('hello world');
```

Which outputs:

```
hello%20world
```

However, how would I call `urlencode`?  The desired output is:

```
hello+world
```

If the short answer is that I simply need to call `urlencode` directly, then so be it.

Comment: It is a native function, why do you need some wrapper for it??

Comment: @Cheery, zf2 explains contextual escaping [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.escaper.theory-of-operation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. The native `rawurlencode()` function produces output according to [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) however `urlencode()` is not. This is main motivation behind the usage of rawurlencode in `escapeUrl()` method. I think you have two options in this case;

**A.** You can try to extend native Escaper and override the escapeUrl() method:

```
namespace My\Escaper;

use Zend\Escaper\Escaper as BaseEscaper;

class Escaper extends BaseEscaper
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function escapeUrl($string)
    {
        return urlencode($string);
    }
}
```

**B.** You can simply use `urlencode()` like @cheery's said in the comments, it's a native function. (Personally i think this is most simple solution)

**UPDATE:**

You may also want to [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996161/199593) about difference between urlencode and rawurlencode in deep.