# Twitter won't share when there's text | in the URL

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

My title text has this character | and hence twitter share isn't working.

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Wall%20Clock%20|%20by%20BestPlace%20http://www.example.com/wall-clock&hashtags=BestPlace
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $heading_title; ?>%20<?php echo 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>&amp;hashtags=fufuh" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">
           Share Twitter
        </a>
```

How do I replace or remove | from the text so twitter would load it properly?

Comment: You may need to force the encode on the pipe character via `<?php echo str_replace('|','%7C',$heading_title); ?>` or do `<?php echo urlencode($heading_title); ?>`

Comment: If you want to embed something in a URL you should [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it.

Comment: Funny though that there is already `%20` between "Wall Clock"... `<?php echo urlencode(urldecode($heading_title)); ?>` to prevent double encoding maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would want to know why your `$heading_title` already contains partial url encoded value...

**Remove/Replace option:**

```
<?php echo str_replace('|','',$heading_title); ?>
```

**Re-Encode option:**

This will remove the current encoding (because your title has `%20` for space) then re-encode it to catch the pipe character.

```
<?php echo urlencode(urldecode($heading_title)); ?>
```

or possibly [rawurlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/urlencode-vs-rawurlencode) to retain the percent notation ( `%20` vs `+` )

```
<?php echo rawurlencode(urldecode($heading_title)); ?>
```