# Pass Multiple query parameter through URL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a path alias like below

> $node_alias = '/node/add/page?id=1';

what i need is have to append query parameter to a destination url with above url,i have tried below but doenn't work

> $node_alias = '/node/add/page?id=1&destination=/admin/content?id=1

Any solution?

Comment: Slashes need to be 'encoded' in URL query strings see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-urlencode-function/ for more details on how to do this in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You need to url-encode each component in the query string.

The first parameter `id=1` is fine, but the `destination` parameter contains special characters used for delimiting uri components : `/`, `?`, `=`.

You can use [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`rawurlencode()`](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) :

```
$node_alias = '/node/add/page?id=1&destination=' . rawurlencode('/admin/content?id=1')
```

There is a drupal way of doing this, using [`drupal_http_build_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7.x) (d7):

```
$path = current_path();
$params = drupal_get_query_parameters() + array('destination' => '/admin/content?id=1');
$query = drupal_http_build_query($params);

$node_alias = $path . '?' . $query;
```

See also [urlencode vs rawurlencode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996139/urlencode-vs-rawurlencode)